# Stories in different sprints shown in PBI

Tags: powerbi, sprint

I have data from Jira ,exported into Excel, and imported into the Power BI.
Here is a subset of data to explain the query:
[image]
Now, For ex., CCD3 is currently in sprint 2.3, and has been bumped back 5 times.  It currently shows in my PBI report in sprint 1.2 (Because just the Sprint column is used at the minute).
I would really like to show, firstly, the correct sprint; but also the count of sprints as a data point for each story.  I could then slice the stories in the current sprint based on whether they’re new for that sprint (count of 1) or have been dragged/delayed from other sprints (count of 2+).

How to attain this in Power BI please?

Thanks,
AP